# Converting Jquery to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm looking for a way to 'convert' my Jquery/JS part into PHP. I know you can do it all with AJAX but my only problem is I don't know how to validate it in PHP, because there are HTML parts that are validate.(Sorry if it isn't clear).

My JS/Jquery part:

```
          function highlight() {

     var timerId = 0;
     var $divs = $('.cell').removeClass('redborder');
     var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $divs.length);

     $divs.eq(random).addClass('redborder');
     console.log($divs.eq(random));

     $('#submit').show();
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#button').click(function () {
         $('p').empty();

         if ($('#plaatje1').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 1</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje2').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 2</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje3').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 3</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje4').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 4</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje5').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 5</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje6').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 6</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje7').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 7</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje8').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 8</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje9').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 9</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje10').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 10</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje11').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 11</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje12').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 12</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje13').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 13</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje14').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 14</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje15').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 15</p>");
         }
         if ($('#plaatje16').hasClass("redborder") == true) {
             $(".textarea").append("<p>Tekst 16</p>");
         }

     });

     $('#submit').click(function () {
         clearInterval(timerId);
     });
 });

 timerId = setInterval(function () {
     highlight();
 }, 1000);
```

My problem is that I don't know how to control in PHP that picture 1 has a redborder class. Is there anyway that I can validate this in PHP. The AJAX basis I already have but the validate part is hard.

Thank you very much for helping, I'm sorry for my misspellings and grammar mistakes. English isn't my mother tongue.

Comment: If you are constantly repeating almost the same exact code, you might want to rethink how you are doing this.

Comment: What is the reason to do this in PHP?

Comment: @putvande It's a 'order from my boss'.

Comment: Well.. how are you generating the HTML? How do you know that for example the element with ID `plaatje16` has a class redborder?

Comment: @putvande There's more code, I will update the post.

Comment: I think it would really help if you try to explain the broader story of what you're trying to do here. Where in the user's interaction is this code running? There's a big difference between PHP and jQuery/Javascript, in that jQuery is run in the browser and PHP runs on the server before the page is sent to the browser. They aren't used in exactly the same ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html><!DOCTYPE html>   
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// The only way it's that you save the name tha contains the class
// plaatje2 in a var


//For example:
$nom_curr_img = 'plaatje2';// this var can has any of values tha you mentioned .

echo "<texarea>";
switch($nom_curr_img){
    case 'plaatje2':
    echo "<p>Tekst 5</p>";
    break;
    //...
    case 'plaatjeN':
    echo "<p>Tekst N</p>";
    break;

}
echo "</textarea>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```